# Can electronic components work without power?

Tags: power-supply, thermocouple, active-components

Can *electronic components* work without power,with the help of temperature?
according to my knowledge,I don't think so,until heat will generate some energy and that will drive component. I have to make a circuit now,which has no power but has temperature of around 130 C
how can I get the power for the circuit from the temperature?

Comment: You mean like with a thermopile?

Comment: Temperature is directly related with the internal ENERGY of something. So temperature difference contains power.

Comment: An old fashioned crystal radio worked without a local power source.

Answer (score 4):

This question is somewhat poorly formed, and the answer depends heavily on how you define "power".

If you define power as [energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy), then the answer is a [quite rigid no](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landauer's_principle) (though there is some theoretical [wiggle room in there](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversible_computing)).

If you define "power" as "a traditional, *external* power source", then you can. For example, the [Seebeck effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_effect) allows electricity to be derived from the **flow** of thermal energy.

In general, it sounds like you're interested in [energy harvesting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_harvesting) type applications, that rely on accumulating and using energy from unusual and novel mechanisms to eliminate the need for batteries or connection to a traditional external power supply.

Comment: problem now is we r not able to generate electricity how much we want , it ll generate very less with that i cant operate mc

Comment: @ashish - I *literally* have no idea what you're trying to express. Can you try maybe using entire words?

Answer (score 2):

Start looking at [thermocouples](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermocouple), [thermopiles](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermopile), and  the [Seebeck effect](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_effect)

An example would be furnaces using this principle to power old thermostats.

From the first link:
"Any junction of dissimilar metals will produce an electric potential related to temperature."

But there needs to be a temperature difference for these devices to work.

Comment: I assume the air around the component isn't the same temperature as the component itself. There's always a temperature difference, but the real question is whether the difference is big enough to be of use.

Comment: I think you need a temp difference on each side of the thermocouple not between ambient and the component.   So if you just out the component in a box of hot air that wouldn't help you much.